# racket: implement function (eval t)

Tags: list, scheme, eval, racket

I am trying to implement a function (eval t) that does the following:

examples:

```
(eval '(2 * (1 + 2))) -> 6

(eval '((3 - (4 / 2)) * 2) -> 2
```

What I have so far is:

```
(define (inner lst)
  ((cond
     ((equal? (second lst) '+) +)
     ((equal? (second lst) '-) -)
     ((equal? (second lst) '*) *)
     ((equal? (second lst) '/) /))
   (first lst) (third lst)))


(define (eval t)
  (cond
    ((and (number? (first t)) (number? (third t))) (inner t))
    ((list? (third t)) (eval `(,(first t) ,(second t) ,(inner (third t)))))
    ((list? (first t)) (eval `(,(inner (first t)) ,(second t) ,(third t))))))
```

It works for:

```
(eval '(1 + (1 + 2))) -> 4

(eval '((1 + 1) + (2 + 2))) -> 6
```

but it does not work for cases like:

```
(eval '((1 + 1) + (1 + (1 + 1))))
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick here is to understand that expressions can take precisely two forms: a raw number datum or a list containing an operation. As a pseudo-grammar, that means each expression must conform to the following structure:

```
expression = number
           | ( expression operator expression )

operator   = +
           | -
           | *
           | /
```

This means that the `eval` function must be able to handle *either* kind of expression, so all of these should work:

```
(eval 7)             ; => 7
(eval '(1 + 6))      ; => 7
(eval '((2 * 3) + 1) ; => 7
```

There are two things to take from this:

1. The `eval` function should be able to handle raw numbers, not just lists containing operators.
2. There are only precisely two cases that should need to be handled in the `eval` function.

This means that `eval` should probably take something like the following form:

```
; eval : expression? -> number?
(define (eval expr)
  (cond
    [(number? x) ???]
    [else        ???]))
```

Your many different cases for your implementation of `eval` are too complex and are unnecessary. You should not need to inspect the structure of a list because it always needs to be evaluated precisely the same way: `eval` the left side, then `eval` the right side, then combine both sides together with the operation in the middle. This works because, if `eval` can cope with numbers, then something like `(eval 3)` will work correctly.

This sounds like a homework problem, so I won’t give away the precise implementation, but hopefully this should be enough to point you in the right direction.